# SqlConnection - is remote or local connection?

Tags: .net, ado.net, sqlconnection

How can I determine is it local connection (localhost or 127.0.0.1) or is it remote connection (other machine in local area) if I have SqlConnection object?

Comment: Because I want to create db copy form my .net application.

If I have local mssql connection I can choose local file path ("c:/tmp/","d:/someolder", etc) and local area path ("\\192.168.0.13\backup").
But if I have remote connnection I must choose only local area path.

Perhaps my path is incorrect?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14197103/check-if-a-sql-server-instance-is-on-local-computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way that I am aware of is to check the connectionstring directly to see if it contains either the words localhost, 127.0.0.1, (localhost), "." or the local machine name. Check for starting with since their could be a local named instance of Sql running.

You can use the System.Environment library to retrieve the current machine name. You can also look at using the ConnectionBuilder library in .Net to retrieve the data without using complete string parsing. Details on this can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254947.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Ask SQL using the connection with the statement

```
SELECT @@SERVERNAME
```

then verifiy if this match the name of the client machine with Environment.MachineName, modulo the SQL instance name

Comment: And what about mssql server alias? - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188635.aspx
Does your way work if I use alias?

Comment: Should work: @@servername is set at setup-time and is the name of the machine/cluster.
Be aware that it represents a cluster you may only access cluster disks (e.g. c$ is not available)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the connection string out of the SqlConnection obejct.

```
string s = connection.ConnectionString;
```

and check the data source or the server element of that string.

**Edit:** Code sample provided.

I think this function should work (not tested anyways).

```
private bool CheckConnectionStringLocalOrRemote(string connectionString) {

        //Local machine
        IPHostEntry entry = Dns.GetHostByAddress("127.0.0.1");

        IPAddress[] addresses = entry.AddressList;
        String[] aliases = entry.Aliases;
        string hostName = entry.HostName;           

        if(connectionString.Contains(hostName))
            return true;



        foreach (IPAddress address in addresses) {
            if (connectionString.Contains(address.ToString())) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        foreach (string alias in aliases) {
            if (connectionString.Contains(alias))
                return true;
        }


        return false;
    }
```

Ps: make sure to add a using statement to System.Net namespace.

Comment: Well, it may be "127.0.0.1", "localhost", "HOME" or "WORK" etc and all of them are aliases of local machine :(

Answer (score 0):

You may check `SqlConnection.ConnectionString` property to see if it has something like `(local)` or `.` in its' `server` part, but that's not very reliable because of `%systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts' and various other SQL Aliases, whereby`foo-srv` may well be a local box.