# Check if a named SQL Server Instance is running on local computer or not

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

You might find the question duplicate to these 2 links ([Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14197103/check-if-a-sql-server-instance-is-on-local-computer) and [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886543/sqlconnection-is-remote-or-local-connection)) but they haven't been answered correctly. Let me brief you the question what i really want.

### Looking For

I am looking for a way through which we can check if the provided ***SQL Instance Name*** is locally available or is residing on another remote computer.

My local SQL Server Instance name is **Office-PC\SQLEXPRESS**

### Solutions i found which didn't work

1) [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14197751/2994869) : When i use the below code it says **remote** while the specified instance is present **local**.

```
SELECT Case when HOST_NAME()=SERVERPROPERTY('Office-PC\SQLEXPRESS') then 'local' else 'remote' end
```

2) I tried using the below code suggested in many comments on different websites. But it is showing incorrect output.

```
print HOST_NAME()    //OUTPUT : Office-PC
print @@SERVERNAME   //OUTPUT : HOME\SQLEXPRESS
```

3) Some people suggested to use the below command to get instance name which works perfectly but it doesn't tell us which of the instance is locally available.

```
SQLCMD -L
```

4) I also read somewhere (can't find the link) that we can get the Instance name from **Registry** itself.

That is all i could find.

If anyone has any other ways to find if the provided named SQL Instance is locally available, then please let me know.

Comment: I'm not clear what context you're in. 1 and 2 suggest you're currently in a SQL session, and you want to find out whether the SQL instance you're *already connected to* is local. But then, local to what??. 3 and 4 suggest you're interactively at a computer, and want to find out about a SQL instance that may or may not be on it. Which is it?

Comment: `HOST_NAME()` and `@@SERVERNAME` work for me.  If I check on a remote connection I get two different results; if I check on the actual server where the SQL Server instance lives I get two identical results.  But this is because the SQL Server instances where I work are named after the server they run on.  So this comes down to configuration?

Comment: If you are connected to the server, `SELECT client_net_address, local_net_address FROM sys.dm_exec_connections WHERE session_id = @@SPID` should do. If `client_net_address` is `<local machine>` or `client_net_address = local_net_address`, then you are connected to a local server. Disclaimer: not thoroughly tested with all possible transports.

Comment: @JeroenMostert it worked perfectly. Please post it as an answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a little  more complicated than I'd like, but `HOST_NAME()` or the server machine name aren't reliable, the following should do:

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN client_net_address IN ('<local machine>', '<named pipe>', local_net_address) THEN 'local' 
    ELSE 'remote' 
END AS [ConnectionType]
FROM sys.dm_exec_connections 
-- The parent_connection_id check covers MARS
WHERE session_id = @@SPID  AND parent_connection_id IS NULL
```

Disclaimer: not thoroughly tested with all possible transports. This works against local memory connections, LocalDB instances and TCP/IP connections, but it may not work correctly if you use the (rare) remote named pipes or VIA transports. These are disabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SERVERPROPERTY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms174396%28v=sql.120%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN HOST_NAME()=SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName') THEN 'local' ELSE 'remote' END
```

> **MachineName**
>
> Windows computer name on which the server instance is running.
>
> For a clustered instance, an instance of SQL Server running on a
>   virtual server on Microsoft Cluster Service, it returns the name of
>   the virtual server.

Comment: i have used this code but it is returning "remote" i have tried using with machine name as well as SQL Instance Name

Comment: That's strange, I have tested it on few local and few remote instances. And it works just fine.

Comment: sorry mate but in my case the "JeroenMostert " answered correctly in the comments section.