# Which aliases can you use to address a local SQLServer-Instance?

Tags: sql-server

I want to check if a server name like ".\INSTANCE" points to a **local** sql server instance. Currently I check the first part for certain strings, which are:

- .
- ::1
- [::1]
- localhost
- 127.0.0.1
- (local)
- the computer name
- additionally I could check for all installed network adapters IPv4 and IPv6 addresses

Since I didn't find this list anywhere and I see no clear scheme (e.g. **(localhost)** and **local** do not work) I'm not sure if there are any other possibilities. So the question is: Is this list complete or what am I missing?

Comment: What IPs/aliases you can use to address the local host has nothing to do with SQL Server; it's determined by the host itself and the DNS server(s) on the network.

Comment: No, this list is not complete. It's possible for the end user to configure literally anything as an [alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/tools/configuration-manager/aliases-sql-server-configuration-manager) to resolve to the local host, or for that matter a DNS alias, or even an IP proxy. There is no 100% reliable way of determining the server is local until resolving and connecting to it. Once connected, you can determine if the connection is local (see, for example, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51166605/4137916) from a fellow I trust).

Comment: Ideally I wouldn't want to connect to the server as I can't be sure if it's running. But I might add a DNS request to my code, thanks.

Comment: Note that aliases you can configure through Configuration Manager can alias *anything* to *anything*. In particular, it's possible to alias `.` or `localhost` to a remote machine (and yes, I've seen people use this, as part of maintaining legacy stuff that had to be fooled into looking elsewhere). So make sure to establish why it is you're determining this, and what it needs to be robust to. If it's just for visual feedback, there's likely no issue. If you have to be *sure* the server is local for security purposes, it's more tricky.

Comment: Generally `.` and `localhost` and `ComputerName` are the only reliable ones. There is also `(localdb)` which is an instance of LocalDB